# The Frozen Wastes

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

My first is in Family and also in Hill

My second in Circle and also in Flood

My third is in Forest and also in Clock

My fourth stands alone in my frozen wastes.

What am I?

Comment: Is there a specific name for a puzzle phrased in this way? I feel like there probably is but I don't know what it is.

Comment: This is similar(ish) to the so-called "Riley Riddle" format, which basically clues a single word by cluing different words whose combination (excluding overlaps) is the solution word.  These are usually tagged [tag:riddle], [tag:word], and [tag:wordplay] - I've added the latter two for you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My first is in Family and also in Hill

> **ant** - sounds like aunt as in family & anthill.

My second in Circle and also in Flood

> **arc** - part of the circumference & Noah's ark.

My third is in Forest and also in Clock

> **tic** - tick (beetle) common in woods & a clock's tic.

My fourth stands alone in my frozen wastes.

> **a** - one singular item.

These together make

> **Antarctica** - a frozen expanse.

---

First Try: Selecting letters for No. 1, No. 2, etc.

> My first is in Fam**il**y and also in H**il**l - choosing **i**
>  My second in Circ**l**e and also in F**l**ood - **l**
>  My third is in F**o**rest and also in Cl**o**ck - **o**
>  My fourth stands alone in my frozen wastes. - choosing **o**

I'm not sure if this holds water but is it an

> [iLoo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ILoo) - a cancelled Microsoft project to develop a Wi-Fi Internet-enabled portable toilet.

Title: Frozen Wastes

> Frozen - this project was put on hold/cut short & Wastes - the iLoo's output.

Comment: Let me just say that if I had known that was a real thing, I would still have not made a question about it

Comment: The rationale for 1 is off, but the result is correct.
You got 4 wrong but everything else is good. You're just one off :P

Comment: For #1 (first part), think of the homophone for the word you describe.

Comment: Thanks @APrough (I think you're right) and Coldfrog - and justly updated

Comment: Still not there on 4, and your final answer is technically not correct. You're still just one off. There are four... something. What are those four things?

Comment: Perhaps the correct answer is just one letter longer with the additional letter coming from clue 4.

Comment: The surprising part about the subject of the first guess is that it was being developed my Microsoft.  I though Apple had a stranglehold on products using that particular naming convention...

Comment: Thank you @hexomino for this singular, first class, final completion.(The autocomplete changed your handle to becoming!)